# Is there a method to show template usage for Elementor?

Tags: elementor

On an inherited site, there is a big library of Saved Templates. Is there a standard method to display where each template is used across the Pages, Posts, and other Templates on the site?

Ideally, it would be good to see *where* the template is used. At a minimum, I'd like to see *how many times* each is used.

I was not able to find any info in Elementor kb and ChatGPT made an incorrect plugin suggestion and then some questionable php and DB querying.

There is a similar function in Element Manager that shows how many times each is used, but not for Templates.

Answer (score 0):

[Elementor](https://elementor.com/help/template-library/) has gone changes recently. To the best of my knowledge there isn't any built in solution. You can try accessing the database directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// Here is a function that queries the database for Elementor template usage
// Note: I did not test it
void queryDatabaseForTemplateUsage() 
{
    // WordPress database connection
    // Replace these with actual WordPress database connection details
    std::string db_host = "database_host";
    std::string db_user = "database_user";
    std::string db_pass = "database_password";
    std::string db_name = "database_name";

    // Connect to the WordPress database
    // You need to use the appropriate MySQL or database connection library for WordPress and again, I haven't gone pass that point so its kinda a placeholder
    std::cout << "Connecting to the WordPress database..." << std::endl;

    // Your actual SQL query to retrieve Elementor template usage
    // This query checks the post meta for Elementor template information
    std::string query = "SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_elementor_template_type'";

    // Go ahead and execute the query and retrieve the results
    // Again - please use the appropriate functions based on your WordPress environment
    std::cout << "Executing database query..." << std::endl;

    // next, process the results and display the Elementor template usage
    std::cout << "Elementor Template Usage:" << std::endl;

    // For example - result set (replace this with actual database result processing)
    std::vector<std::string> results = {"Page 1: Template A", "Post 1: Template B", "Page 2: Template A"};

    for (const auto& result : results) 
    {
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    // Call the custom database query function
    queryDatabaseForTemplateUsage();
    return 0;
}
```

Not much. I know. But some place to begin with...

Comment: Thank you @michael-haephrati. I appreciate the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for a better answer. Not convicing me the resolution method...
Probably a simple query could be better, like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_title, p.post_name, p.post_type, pm.* FROM `w_posts` p INNER JOIN `w_postmeta` pm
ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_value like '%"template_id":"your_template_id"%'
AND p.post_type != 'revision';
```

Then you must replace the string "your_template_id" with the template post ID.